# I want to reinstall Ubuntu but I do not know which partitions to delete

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

[image: gparted screenshot]

So, I went to GParted and I know that I must delete the ext4 partition and the Linux Swap partition. My question is, does that unknown partition have anything to do with Linux? Should I delete that one too?

Comment: I would suggest having Ubuntu on a separate disk simply to avoid corrupting your Windows installation accidentially.

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu is on `/dev/sdb8` and `/dev/sdb9`. As a general rule of thumb, you want to remove any `ext4` and `linux-swap` partitions. `nfts` partitions and ones flagged `msftres` are related to Windows, and your `fat32` partition is required for UEFI systems to boot, so don't delete that unless you know exactly what you're doing. Good luck!

Comment: Just start the live cd and it will guide you...

Answer (score 2):

*msftres* is the **"Microsoft Reserved" Partition**. It's used by some Windows tools, so if you are not going to delete Windows, you shouldn't delete this partition.

msftres is needed only for conversion from a basic disk to dynamic disk in Windows; it has nothing to do with Linux.

[Reference: Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302873)

See also [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parted/+bug/397386) which has some explanation of msftres oriented towards using Linux partitioning tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is already installed on the `/dev/sdb8` partition.

Boot from Ubuntu live USB ..., when the partition manager (Gparted) prompt mark the `/dev/sdb8` as `/` root with `ext4` file system , select `/dev/sdb9` partition as `swap`, then confirm to install the system.